# Find appropriate data storage and search engine

Tags: c++, qt, search, nosql, key-value

I have many objects. Each object is accosiated with a number of key-value pairs. Key is an arbitrary string (keys may be different for different objects, and there is no full list of possible keys), value can be numeric, string, datetime, etc.

I need to search through this collection using complex search queries. In the simpliest implementation, the user must be able to specify a list of interesting keys and a condition on each key's value, e.g.

```
key1: not present
key2: present
key3: == "value3"
key4: < 42
key5: contains "value5"
```

The engine must find all objects which satisfy all conditions (i.e. conditions are AND'ed). In the perfect implementation, the user is able to specify the condition using some query language, e.g.

```
key1 = "value1" AND (key2 < 3 OR key3 < 3)
```

I'm using C++ with Qt on Windows (Linux support would be not necessary but good). I don't want to use databases that require some installation (especially with administrator rights), I want the solution to be portable.

Please suggest a good way to implement this from scratch or using any library or database that satisfy my needs.

**Upd:** the question is about storing large data amounts on disk and fast searching through it. Maybe also it's about parsing and processing search queries. It is not about data structures I need to use to represent data in memory. It's simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

If they keys are unique, use `std::map` or (C++11) `std::unordered_map`.

If the keys are not unique, use `std::multimap` or (C++11) `std::unordered_multimap`.

The latter have O(1) search and insert, but require that you provide a quality hashing algorithm (not easy to make) and possibly re-hash the map as it grows & shrinks.

Searching is provided by the containers.

Serialization is left as an excercise for the reader.

Comment: There is quite much data. Loading all of it in memory will take some time. However lookup after this will be fast. Do you think it's the best option? Are there any technologies that provides fast lookup without loading all data in memory?

Comment: Sure you can go to disk and skip around when searching for keys.  Way beyond the scope of your question though, sorry.  Check out Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming."

Comment: This is not beyond the scope of my question, it is what I've tried to ask in my question. The simpliest implementation of this would be too slow. I'm looking for something to speed up searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Nested Maps like std::map<key1,std::map<key2,value>>....
```